# Classify csv files in different folders according to their name

Tags: database, bash, csv

I have a lot of csv files that I want to classify according to their filename in different folders.

1. If the file *lefto.csv save them in a folder called lefto
2. If the file *righto.csv save it in a folder called right
3. If the file *sagital.csv save it in a folder called sagittal
4. If the file does not obey any previous condition, save the file in a folder called animals

So far I have been using the mv command, but I would like to make a loop

Comment: are those csv files located within a single folder?

Comment: you tags are not really reflecting what you want to use, plus, show us some code that you are using now and you want to improve

Answer (score 2):

**`bash`** solution:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    if [[ "$f" =~ .*(lefto|righto|sagital).csv ]]; then
        mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        mv "$f" "animals"
    fi
done
```

Comment: great use of group capture with `BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for